# How to add foreign key in a table where column value can come from two different tables?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, hierarchy

I have three tables

```
create table main_comments (
   id serial primary key,
   comment text not null 
);

create table sub_comments (
   id serial primary key,
   main_id integer not null,
   comment text not null ,
   foreign key (main_id) references main_comments(id) on delete cascade 
); 

create table report (
  id serial primary key ,
  comment_id integer not null ,
  table_type bool ,
  report text not null 
);
```

in report table `comment_id` column's value can come from `main_comments` or `sub_comments`. so avoiding the confusion i add `table_type` column which tell from where `comment_id` value comes from like main or sub table. But now i want to add foreign key to `report` table.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: what would i write after references ? Both table's names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you structure your comments like this,

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
   comment_id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   parent_id  int REFERENCES comments,
   comment text NOT NULL
);
```

Then you three advantages,

- you don't have the problem about having to reference sub-comments AND comments
- you can go more than one layer deep
- the schema between subcomments and comments is in sync

For more information see the [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) and [hierarchy](/questions/tagged/hierarchy) badges.